# how i do use puppet variable in facter custom facts

Tags: puppet, facter

how i can inherit variable from puppet manifest in facter custom fact? in this case $job_name varible. I want use same custom fact with different envs.

```
if $facts['hostname'] =~ /.*name.*/ {

$job_name = 'test'

        file {  "/opt/$job_name":
                ensure => directory,
                owner  => 'root',
                group  => 'root',
                mode   => '0775',
             }


        file { "/opt/$job_name/version.$job_name":
                ensure => present,
                owner  => 'root',
                group  => 'root',
                mode   => '0644',
                #notify => Exec["update_test"],
                source => "puppet:///modules/test/version.$job_name",
             }


     if $facts['check_version'] == "aasdadsadasd" {

        file {  "/opt/$job_name/bla2":
                ensure => directory,
                owner  => 'root',
                group  => 'root',
                mode   => '0775',
             }


     }
```

my custom fact rb code is

```
require 'facter'
Facter.add(:check_version) do
  setcode do
    Facter::Core::Execution.exec("/bin/cat /opt/$job_name/version.$job_name")
  end
end
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a manifest variable in a custom fact, you can't. This is because facts are evaluated on the client before the catalog (collection of manifests) is compiled. So at the point that your custom fact is run, the variable `$job_name` doesn't actually exist yet.